# Change class of element in template

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I have an html template which, on click on a button, I clone and append to a div. I want to change the class name of a div which is nested inside the template, however, I do not know how. I tried looking it up but I couldn't find any way to do that in JavaScript, the only posts I found were about Visual Studio Code etc, however, as mentioned, I want to do this in JavaScript.

The template look something like this:

```
<template id="newElement">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <p>Test Paragraph</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

This is how I clone and append the template:

```
function addElement() {

    var listElement = document.getElementById('newElement');
    var cloneTemplate = listElement.content.cloneNode(true);
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.appendChild(cloneTemplate);
    cloneTemplate.removeAttribute("id");

}
```

Now, I want to change the class of the newly generated element. I tried this using:

```
cloneTemplate.content.className = "newName";
cloneTemplate.className = "newName";
```

I also tried accessing the div inside the template and changing its class, however, I keep getting the error message that the element I try to access is undefined. 
Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Comment: You need to learn about scope.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript

Comment: What do you mean? I'm trying to change the class name inside the addElement() function so it shouldn't be a problem or am I being slow here?

Comment: @SennerP this is not really relevant as I know how to change a class name generally, the problem is that I'm having trouble accessing the element whose name I want to change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you log the content of `var cloneTemplate`  you will receive something like this: `DocumentFragment [ #text, div.wrapper, #text ]`

Selecting the `div.wrapper` by `var div = cloneTemplate.querySelector( 'div.wrapper' );` and changing its class to `div.className = 'newName';` will result in your desired output.

Put together in your function:

```
function addElement() {
    var listElement = document.getElementById('newElement');
    var cloneTemplate = listElement.content.cloneNode(true);

    var div = cloneTemplate.querySelector( 'div.wrapper' );
    div.className = 'newName';

    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    list.appendChild(cloneTemplate);
}
```

Removed `cloneTemplate.removeAttribute("id");` because it throws an error and your cloned content does not contain any id's.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, it worked perfectly! I have a question though, earlier, when I went through different stuff to try to change the class name, I tried using querySelectorAll where you used querySelector, however, it didn't work. Do you know why that is (I hope that doesn't stray too far from my initial question)

Comment: querySelectorAll will return a NodeList ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll ) whereas querySelector returns the first element ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector )